# Windows Azure: importing data from Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Windows Azure mobile service with a sql database.

I was wondering if it's possible to insert records from an excel sheet to an azure database table.

in other words, I have an excel sheet with many data records, I want to export the records to a database table.

is there any tool/service/SDK that provides this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a tool that does that natively, but you can save your data in Excel as a CSV file, and use the BCP utility to load that data into any SQL database.  Here is an [older blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/05/21/10014019.aspx) about the use of BCP with Azure SQL Database to get you started. If you are familiar with SSIS, you could import your data that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try that that through SSMS normally (edit all rows and then just add it :-)) or use Access to connect to the front end?